# How to secure a web service called from Android

Tags: android, security, oauth

I have a SSL enabled web service that is called from an Android app that I'd like to secure access to. Specifically, when the service is called I want to know the identity of the caller. My initial idea is to have the user authenticate on Android via Oauth. Then, that access token would be sent in the web service call. On the server I would call Google with the token to see if the user is in the approved list. Is this a feasible approach or is there a better alternative.

Comment: you can check user-agent for differentiate calls from android/web/iphone.

Comment: I have some suggestions on this, but I should clarify before making assumptions about security. Given that you have an SSL channel for the HTTP(S) calls, and your server has an SSL certificate for the HTTPS client stack to validate, then your channel should be considered trusted for sending sensitive data.  Assuming that is true, then your Android app could have a name/password box in its own UI. Seems like a simple challenge response (or just send the name/password up) as part of the web service to obtain a token could work.

Comment: Sure, but I'd rather not deal with passwords. I'd like to use Google Oauth so that I don't need to require users to register and remember another password. Also you shouldn't have to sign in to use the app since you're already authenticated on Android

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to watch this great video.
[Google I/O 2011: Evading Pirates and Stopping Vampires](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnSNCXR9fbY#at=2273)
It was very useful for me, and may be for you.

Comment: I did watch that and it was interesting however that talk is concerned with preventing piracy via license management